# How to store user choice using html and Js

Tags: javascript, html, data-storage

I am working on making an online quiz. I wish to store the option user chooses and time spent per question.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sessionStorage.getItem('name')` to get the stored data and `sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'value')`.

To get the time elapsed in seconds, you can start the timer with `const start_time = new Date();` and end it with `const end_time = new Date();` and `const elapsed_seconds = (end_time - start_time) / 1000`;